# Is there any native php function that adds 2 array's value together?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any native php function that adds 2 array's value together ?

Like lets say:

```
$array1= array(1 => 10, 2 =>20, 3=>3);

$array2= array(1 => 11, 2 =>22, 3=>33);

$somearray = array1 + array2;
```

and the output of that will be:

```
array(1 => 21, 2 => 42, 3=>36);
```

Not looking for a function or a way to do this with a `foreach`
Just asking if there's a native php function that does that, i am looking on array functions at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php and either i am missing it or it doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: There is no built-in function for this.  You need to use a loop (or a function like `array_map`/`array_walk`).

Comment: Why would i be down voted the question is legit, the spelling and grammar is mostly correct ... bah

Comment: Why would any language add functions for specific use cases such as this? PHP's core is a mess of barely-used functions as it is, write your own function once in a while

Comment: @Xeoncross: That would return a single number, the OP wants an array.  The sum of each key in the 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map(function($x, $y) { return $x + $y }, $array1, $array2)` should do, if you like that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks @hobbs this is close enough, i wanted to preserve keys though, however i guess i will have to use a loop...